# Large Sample Properties Least Square Estimator

Tags: estimation, least-squares, julia

I am trying to understand the properties of the least squares estimator. In particular the Gauss-Markov theorem states that the estimator is independent from the distribution of the error term.

Thus if I understand correctly, the following should be true:

$\beta | e \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2) == \beta|e\sim Beta(2,5)$

However when I tried out an example I got slightly different results:

```
#code in julia 
(() -> begin
   n = 10000
   A = [ones(n) rand(n)]
   β = [3.1, 12.7]
   y = A * β + rand(Beta(2,5), n)
   b = inv(A'A)A'y
   print(b)
end)()

> 3.38 12.69
```

and

```
(() -> begin
   n = 10000
   A = [ones(n) rand(n)]
   β = [3.1, 12.7]
   y = A * β + rand(Normal(), n)
   b = inv(A'A)A'y
   print(b)
end)()

> 3.10 12.71
```

Now the normal distributed errors are indeed unbiased estimators, while for the Beta distribution there seems to be a bias of $3.38 - 3.10$ for the intercept which according to theory should not be there, right?

Comment: You;d need the error term to have mean 0. The Beta(2,5) distribution doesn't have mean 0

Comment: thank you for the comment. Can you post this as an answer.

Comment: I probably shouldn't - one line answers aren't really acceptable. I may be able to figure out something more to add though.

Comment: To be honest it was not a very smart question to begin with =). It makes sense that a RV with a mean not equal to zero introduces a bias.

Comment: I'll post something soon